# Flutter: How to use FirebaseAuth idTokenChange?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

If I logged in, go to the main page without log in again.

like this

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User firebaseuser = _auth.currentUser;
  if (firebaseuser == null) {
    return runApp(MaterialApp(home: login()));
  } else {
    return runApp(MaterialApp(home: MainPage()));
  }
```

however `currentUser` description says

> You should not use this getter to determine the users current state,
> instead use [authStateChanges], [idTokenChanges] or [userChanges] to
> subscribe to updates.

So I decided to use `idTokenChanges`.

because it says

> Notifies about changes to the user's sign-in state (such as sign-in or
> sign-out) and also token refresh events.

And I made it like this

```
Stream<User> loginstate = await FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges();
```

But i don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `authStateChanges` for only user sign-in state updates, not `idTokenChanges`.  There is an example working with its stream in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

`idTokenChanges` is for getting updates to the user's ID token, which will refresh every hour.

Comment: Does `idTokenChanges` include all events in `authStateChanges` as well as the token changes? So if I want to listen to both, I can just listen to `idTokenChanges` and not have two streams?